# Select Rings in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to select rings on mesh made in geometry nodes.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you capture the curve *Factor* before conversion, it survives on mesh vertices. The mesh-edges around the profile will have the same *Factor* at both ends. That can be used to identify them:

[image]

This example deletes the other, longitudinal, edges.

Someone may come up with a better way. For some uses, you could convert the original: *Curve to Points* ('Evaluated'), and just instance the profile curve on the points, in the points' output: 'Rotation', to  create the same set of edges that would have been the rings of a *Curve to Mesh*.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You